# How to parse PendingIntent and obtain the corresponding intent？

Tags: android

I know the PendingIntent project is obtained by `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, ... , intent, ...) function`.

After I use notification, the information needed to skip stores to intent. then the intent encapsulate into `PendingIntent`. now I want to get the intent by `pendingIntent`. or I want to get the intent information how by `pendingIntent`. how could I get the intent?

The sender:

```
Intent openintent = new Intent(this, ZXReaderAbout.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, openintent, 0);//send openintent  intent to system when click information
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "11", "22", contentIntent);
```

Receiving section:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = notification.contentIntent;
```

That is to say it can obtain the encapsulate intent from the `pIntent`.

Any suggestion is very grateful.